# How to use `ng-click` inside `.innerHtml`?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have added one icon dynamically inside div element using `.innerHtml`.div element has `ng-click` event.

```
function init() {

    info.update = function(props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = '<div class="refreshMap"><a  ng-click="setView()" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></div>';
    };
    info.addTo(map);
    $compile(info)($scope);
}


$scope.setView =function() {
            map.setView([ "13.01897", "80.2067" ], 17);
        }
```

`click` event is not firing here.How can I use ng-click inside `.innerHtml`?

Comment: what is `info`?  It doesn't look like an angular element, and therefore not something that could be handled by `$compile`..... Normally setting `innerHTML` with angular is a bad practice.

Comment: try this **angular.element(document.querySelector('<id-selector>')).append($compile(<innerHTML>)($scope))**

Comment: @manishkumar `angular.element(this._div).html($compile('<div class="refreshMap"><a  ng-click="setView()" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></div>'));` is this correct?

Comment: @laz did u get it working ?